# AMP performance are really strange

Tags: google-search-console, amp

It's a month that I google started to offer an AMP version of my blog's posts.

After that month I opened my Search Console, opeing to see improvments in the performance, but for my surprise things were actually the oposite

As you can see, in any simension my site performs worse on the AMP pages.

In this screen you can find mobile pages only. As you can see the total clicks are higher, but since the impressions are almost double on the AMP pages, the CTR is really low, and the position is the same.

[image: My site GA stats]

Can you guys explain to me why:

- I see the normal page in the mobile search results? It was suppose to be AMP only.
- Why my AMP page ranks worse than its non AMP version?
- Why the total CTR got worse.

It's so strange guys...

Thank you.

Comment: Whenever I add any scripts in my website and change internal css to external or vise versa, result are always different. I don't use AMP because I don't use any external scripts so there is no need to add Google amp js, which really slow down webpage by making external http request and loading whole JS which is also not cached for long time. I like the concept of AMP css, which don't allowed to use such a css property, so browser repaint done in fast way. The comment is just for if you're familiar with web developing :D

Comment: Thanks man. Yes I am familiar. I'm a frontend dev.... Yap, it does call an external, but the revenue theoretically is big, since google will better rank you, which does not happen in my case....

Comment: AMP is not ranking factor at yet, and I don't think they will also consider in near future. Sites like Amazon can perform really better in terms of speed. AMP may gives you top position for their AMP box only.